# Is it possible to re-launch and test xsbti.AppMain derived application from sbt?

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm developing [an sbt launched application](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Detailed-Topics/Launcher.html#creating-a-launched-application) with custom [command line interface](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Extending/Command-Line-Applications.html).
The problem is that every time I want to test it I have to remove the previously published `boot` directory and then recompile and publish locally the artefacts, and then finally run the app and test it manually. Part of this is accomplished by running external shell scripts.

How could I make `sbt` doing the job for me? I've already made the skeleton command for it:

```
  lazy val root = Project(
    id       = "app",
    base     = file("."),
    settings = buildSettings ++ Seq( resolvers := rtResolvers,
      libraryDependencies ++= libs,
      scalacOptions  ++= Seq("-encoding", "UTF-8", "-deprecation", "-unchecked"),
      commands ++= Seq(launchApp))
  )


  val launchApp = Command.command("launch") { state =>
    state.log.info("Re-launching app")
    state
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Create [launcher configuration](http://www.scala-sbt.org/1.0/docs/Launcher-Configuration.html) file, e.g. `fqb.build.properties` in the project's main directory.
2. Create a script that launches the application

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/env bash

   java -jar /path/to/sbt-launch.jar "$@"
   ```
3. Define task and command:

   ```
   lazy val launcherTask = TaskKey[Unit]("launch", "Starts the application from the locally published JAR")

   lazy val launchApp: Seq[Setting[_]] = Seq(
       commands += Command.command("publish-launch") { state =>
       state.log.info("Re-launching app")
       val modulesProj = modules.id
       s"$modulesProj/publishLocal" ::
         "publishLocal" ::
         launcherTask.key.label ::
         state
     },
     launcherTask := {
       "launch @fqb.build.properties" !<
     }
   )
   ```
4. Add it as a setting to a project:

   ```
   lazy val root = Project(
       id       = "app",
       base     = file("."),
       settings = buildSettings ++ Seq( resolvers := rtResolvers,
         libraryDependencies ++= libs,
         scalacOptions  ++= Seq("-encoding", "UTF-8", "-deprecation", "-unchecked"),
         launchApp)
   )
   ```

Remember to delete old `~/.<app_name>` directory when re-deploying, so the changes could take effect.